# Make ticks at means of variables using stat_summary()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can I produce ticks highlighting the mean values of three factor variables in a barplot drawn with `stat_summary()`?

I made this graph:

```
CarPlot <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=mpg)) +
  stat_summary(aes(fill = factor(gear)), fun.y=mean, geom="bar")
```

and tried to add `scale_y_continuous(breaks=round(..y..,2))` to exploit the internally computed value `..y..`, but it didn't work. Would I have to compute all means for all groups first and hand this over to `scale_y_continuous()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing will give you the best control, but you can do something like:

```
CarPlot <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=mpg)) +
           stat_summary(aes(fill = factor(gear)), fun.y=mean, geom="bar")

cpgg <- ggplot_build(CarPlot)

CarPlot + scale_y_continuous(breaks=cpgg$data[[1]]$y)
```

[image]

to take advantage of the work ggplot2 has already done for you.